# Match a master list with a duplicate list of the same things and then show all of the matched data from a different cell as the answer

Tags: excel, indexing, match

trying to match wells that come up more then once with a master list of the wells, but then when they match I want to be able to see the comment that was made about that well in the column that is beside it.

essentially match column A (which has many duplicates of column H) with column H, then when matched show all the comments from column E in the answer cell.

I want to be able to see all the comments that have been made about that well in one cell instead of having to search the spread sheet all of the time.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions about the way that your data is set up, however I am thinking that a pivot table with a slicer would do what you want. Take a look at the graphic and see if it is doing what you're asking:

[image]

Comment: That is almost exactly what I am looking for, does the data in your unknown columns come up as well?

Comment: Also do you think its at all possible to use Index Match function for this sort of data setup?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the data displayed in the pivot table.

Comment: This update shows that an Index function formula will work, although it is not an Index/Match formula. To me it is less efficient than the pivot table however.